# What can I do if my academic references are not responsive?

Tags: recommendation-letter, email, communication

I provided references of two Professors from my previous University. I talked to them before supplying the references.

I believe, the universities sent some Emails asking them for some kind of confidential report. They are procrastinating responding to the Emails from the universities I applied to.

They are not even responding to my calls and mails:

- I contacted them last week of December to let them know about the reference.
- Sent SMS text on 11th January after I had submitted the application.
- I also sent them personal Emails on 15th January.
- Called them on 18th January.

I believe the last date is 31st January.

How can I get around problems like this in future?

Is there any formal way to submit applications without references?

Comment: By "supplying references" I assume you mean you "asked them to write you a letter of recommendation." By teachers, do you mean professors? Or are these teachers from a high school? Or teaching assistants? How much time have you given them? When are the deadlines? You said you talked to them - I'm assuming they agreed to write reference letters?

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but I asked several clarifying questions and you only answered the last one. All of the questions I asked are pertinent to even attempting to answer your question or give some suggestions.

Comment: "Respond to emails" could mean almost anything. They could be automated emails asking them to submit a reference electronically or by mail. They could be emails asking "Did you work with anonymous? Could you verify ____ about them?" They could be emails asking for a more informal assessment "What do you think of anonymous?" My other questions, which you gave no information about, are still unanswered. Frankly, if this is typical of the way you ask for help from people, now editing your comment to say what I "missed," that might explain why you aren't getting any response.

Comment: The general script is: ask for letters with the prospective due dates, preferably a month in advance of needing them; send an email to let them know they should be getting an email from the program that requests them to upload the letter; send a reminder email 3-5 days before the due date (assuming more than a week has passed since your last email); if not received yet then send them a reminder email the day before/of the deadline with the time due; if the deadline has passed, or you have some reason to think they aren't going to do what they said, get additional help. Where are you in this?

Comment: @BrianDHall, I contacted them last week of December to let them know about the reference. Sent SMS text on 11th January after I had submitted the application. Called them on 18th January. I believe the last date is 31st January.

Comment: @BrianDHall, I also sent them personal Emails on 15th January.

Comment: Echoing BrianDHall's timeline, you should be patient, and please stop pestering your references. If you still haven't heard from them by the end of next week, send them another, **polite** email that simply reminds them of the deadline.

Comment: Also see [this previous question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36536/sending-a-second-reminder-to-a-professor-about-lors-after-the-first-reminder) which might help you.

Comment: The deadline for letter submission is 31 January? What's the problem? They still have more than 10 days to submit.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but read this: http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/recommendations/index.html  You might send an "I thought this might help" email with the info listed to your referees.  You do not need a FERPA release, but *read and heed* my advice about waiver of right to access.

Comment: Oh, I think the issue might be that you expected things to be turned in well before the published deadline - which is not generally how most people behave in, well, any situation. I think the earliest I had any reference letter turned in was about 4 days before my earliest deadline, and the latest was about 30 minutes before the posted deadline. Sounds like they are doing ok, but how useful call/text is will vary by the professor, and would only really make sense if you know that this is actually useful to them. It's quite natural to feel panicked with things out of your control like this.